# Uncaught TYPO3 Exception in RSA.php line 228

Tags: php, rsa

I have a nicely working extension for typo3 which fails for PHP 5.3:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1: 
    PHP : Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
    Crypt/RSA.php line 228
```

I tried:

```
ini_set('error_reporting','E_ALL &  ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT');
```

but with this, errors, notices are gone with blank output where some encrypted output is expected.

Comment: I removed all **&new** by **new** and then there are no errors. but the output is blank. for older versions of php, it still works fine after changes. fails for php 5.3 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Crypt/RAS/Math/GMP.php

line. No. 63

```
if (!@dl('gmp.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX) && !@dl('php_gmp.' . PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX)) {

------------------------

bool dl ( string $library )
```

This function has been removed from some SAPI's in PHP 5.3.

Ref. http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

The same changes will be in Crypt/RAS/Math/BigInt.php and Crypt/RAS/Math/BCMath.php